# PHP foreach multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I've inherited a site that holds a form to insert values into a Mysql db. It works fine, but I've been asked to add a field and can't seem to work it out.

This is the code:

```
<table id="target-language">
<tr>
<?php
$rowCount=-1;
foreach( $languages as $key=>$value ){
    if( isset( $_SESSION['formvalues']['addEntry']['target'] ) ){
        if( in_array( $value, $_SESSION['formvalues']['addEntry']['target'] ) )
            $selected = " checked=\"checked\"";
        else    
            $selected = "";
    }
    $sqlDepartments = "SELECT depName FROM tbldepartements WHERE langId = '".trim($value)."'";
    $departments = mysql_query( $sqlDepartments ) or die( mysql_error() );

    if( $rowCount == 0 ){
        echo "</tr>\n<tr>";
        $rowCount = 0;
    }else
        $rowCount++;
?>
<td align="right">
<?php echo $value; ?><input type="checkbox" name="target[]" value=<?php echo "\"".$value."\"" . $selected; ?> />

<select name="department_<?php echo $value ?>">
<?php while( $department = mysql_fetch_object( $departments ) ): ?>
<?php
        $curDepartment = $_SESSION['formvalues']['addEntry']['departments'][$value];
            if(  $curDepartment == utf8_encode($department->depName) )
                $optionSelected = ' selected="selected"';
            else
                $optionSelected = ''; 
?>                                                                                         
    <option value="<?php echo utf8_encode($department->depName); ?>"<?php echo $optionSelected; ?>><?php echo utf8_encode($department->depName); ?></option>
<?php endwhile; ?>
        <option value=""></option>
</select>
<?php
}
?>
```

This shows a list of languages (DE, UK, ...) with a checkbox, and a dropdown menu with departments in another column. Users can select a language and a department combination and this gets put in the database. (by use of the $_SESSION).
Like:

```
     langauge |checkbox |dropdown list
```

Now I would like a third column added to this. So users would be able to select a language (check the checkbox), and then select a department and enter a jobnumber. 
Like

```
    langauge |checkbox |dropdown list |entry field
```

However, anything I put after the

```
    <select name="department_<?php echo $value ?>">
```

block does not get picked up, and I can't store this in the session value.

Is it possible to have the foreach loop hold multiple values? So checking a language would result in two values being stored in a session to insert into the DB? If so, what would I need to add  to acquire this?

I have some PHP knowledge, but this is a bit much for me :)

Kind regards, and if you need more info, let me know and I'll supply all the needed info.

Comment: what is `$value`? in `<select name="department_<?php echo $value ?>">`you forgot a `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use and(&) operator in PHP foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I've managed to solve the problem by creating a second array consisting of the the entry field and the language, and inserting those into a SESSION to insert in the DB.

Thanks everyone for having a look, and for the use of the and(&) operator in the loop. I haven't used it, but it was an interesting read, and I atleast learned some things :)